# how to enable Floating notification or Heads-Up in react native using react-native-push notification in Android

Tags: android, react-native, localnotification, react-native-push-notification

how to enable floating notification in react native using react-native-push-notification using PushNotification.localNotification({}). I have to receive notification in foreground[text] but somehow, I can't found any solution for how to enable floating notification or Heads-Up enable in react -native Android side.

also,
below I have to attached image of notification in android 13 OS device SS

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ffxd.jpg)

```
  pushNotification = () => {
    PushNotification.configure({
      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log('TOKEN:', token);
      },

      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        PushNotification.localNotification({
          channelId: '',
          foreground: false,
          bigText:
            'My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded. Styling can be done using HTML tags(see android docs for details)', // (optional) default: "message" prop
          subText: 'This is a subText',
          priority: 'high',
          importance: Importance.HIGH,
          invokeApp: true,
          senderID: '587123796145',
          popInitialNotification: true,
          requestPermissions: true,
        });
      },
    });
  };
```

I need this type of notification setting in coding side in react native using  react native push notification (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rsKO.jpg)